# Yodlee TransactionView and ItemId

Tags: yodlee

How does one get the corresponding ItemId of a TransactionView object? I am running a transaction search for a user context (meaning I am not limiting the search to specific ItemId's) and I don't see any data on the TransactionView object that would indicate I can retrieve the ItemId the transaction relates to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 ways to get this required information:

1. The Transaction view object which is coming as the response for your search using user context, in that response you will be able to receive the ItemAccountId to which each transaction belongs.
   Then you can explicitly call http://developer.yodlee.com/Indy_FinApp/Aggregation_Services_Guide/REST_API_Reference/Account%2F%2FSummary%2F%2FAll
   This will get you all the itemIds and its related ItemAccountIds and that can be mapped it to each transaction.
2. Alternate way which we advise is: First use [getItemSummaryForItem1](http://developer.yodlee.com/Indy_FinApp/Aggregation_Services_Guide/REST_API_Reference/getItemSummaryForItem1) API to get the account level information and itemAccountId for each account.
   Then you can continue for calling transaction search which you are doing as of now and map the transactions using itemAccountId.